# MongoDB multiple/nested aggregations

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, relational-database, aggregation

I have these collections:

`users`

```
{
  _id: "userId1",
  // ...
  tracks: ["trackId1", "trackId2"],
};
```

`tracks`

```
{
  _id: "trackId1",
  // ...
  creatorId: "userId1",
  categoryId: "categoryId1"
}
```

`categories`

```
{
  _id: "categoryId1",
  // ...
  tracks: ["trackId1", "trackId15", "trackId20"],
};
```

by using the following code, I am able to get a track by its ID and add the creator

```
tracks.aggregate([
        {
          $match: { _id: ObjectId(trackId) },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            let: { userId: { $toObjectId: "$creatorId" } },
            from: "users",
            pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$userId"] } } }],
            as: "creator",
          },
        },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ])
      .toArray();
```

Response:

```
"track": {
    "_id": "trackId1",
    // ...
    "categoryId": "categoryId1",
    "creatorId": "userId1",
    "creator": {
        "_id": "userId1",
        // ...
        "tracks": [
            "trackId5",
            "trackId10",
            "trackId65"
        ]
    }
}
```

but what I am struggling with is that I want the `creator.tracks` to aggregate also returning the tracks by their ID (e.g up to last 5), and also to get the last 5 tracks from the `categoryId`

expected result:

```
"track": {
    "_id": "trackId1",
    // ...
    "categoryId": "categoryId1",
    "creatorId": "userId1",
    "creator": {
        "_id": "userId1",
        "tracks": [
            {
                "_id": "trackId5",
                // the rest object without the creator
            },
            {
                "_id": "trackId10",
                // the rest object without the creator
            },
            {
                "_id": "trackId65",
                // the rest object without the creator
            },
        ]
    },
    // without trackId1 which is the one that is being viewed
    "relatedTracks": [
        {
            "_id": "trackId15",
            // the rest object without the creator
        },
        {
            "_id": "trackId20",
            // the rest object without the creator
        },
    ]
}
```

I would appreciate any explanation/help to understand what is the best one to do it and still keep the good performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- start from a track
- join with users using the trackId get all the tracks of the creator
  (creator-tracks)
- join with categories using the categoryId to get all the tracks of the category (related tracks)
- remove from related-tracks the tracks of the creator
- take the last 5 from both using `$slice` (creator-tracks and related-tracks)

*i added 2 extra lookups to get all info of the tracks, its empty arrays because i dont have enough data(i have only `trackId1`), with all the data it will work

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b4997)

```js
db.tracks.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "trackId1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "creatorId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "creator-tracks"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "creator-tracks": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$creator-tracks.tracks",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "categories",
      "localField": "categoryId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "related-tracks"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "related-tracks": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$related-tracks.tracks",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "related-tracks": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$related-tracks",
          "cond": {
            "$not": [
              {
                "$in": [
                  "$$this",
                  "$creator-tracks"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "creator-tracks": {
        "$slice": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$creator-tracks",
              "cond": {
                "$ne": [
                  "$$this",
                  "$_id"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          -5
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "related-tracks": {
        "$slice": [
          "$related-tracks",
          -5
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "tracks",
      "localField": "creator-tracks",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "creator-tracks-all-info"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "tracks",
      "localField": "related-tracks",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "related-tracks-all-info"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: thanks, the related tracks should be taken from `track.categoryId`, the user gets a track and sees the creator's 5 last tracks, and the last 5 tracks of the track's category so when the user opens the track's page he can see them, last creator tracks and related tracks based on the same category

Comment: i updated the answer i think this is now what you wanted

Comment: thanks, thats the structure I want, last thing, if you check the results of the URL above, how can I lookup for the `creator-tracks` array? so it will return an array of track objects rather than just the IDs (same for the category) maybe the response could be `"track": { ..., "related-tracks": { "creator": [{ track }, { track }] }, category: [{ track}] }}`

Comment: ok i think you want for each track all track information, i updated to do 2 more lookups after you finish, to get the extra info for those 5 + 5 tracks. We dont have the data for tracks 15/20 etc so its empty, but it will work if we had the complete data

Comment: this is exactly what I needed! thanks! if you can help me adjust it, I am trying to set the filter for the `creator.tracks` too, so in this case the match _id will not be sent inside the creator's tracks the same as the category. also can I run the query without returning `related-tracks` and `creator-tracks` but still use them to query the array of IDs or i need to delete it using plain JS? I have made some changes you can see https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bm-g08dbfuv

Comment: also if you see the `creatorLatestTracks` in the example I sent above, it returns track 1 and 4 only, it should sent 2, 3, 4 since all of them created by that user and 1 is the one I am querying so it should filter

Comment: in the data that i use i dont have track 2,track 3 etc,you gave data for 1 track only, in last update i remove the track from the creator-tracks (i added one more filter). Now creator tracks have all except the trackID(where we started), and category has all except the creators tracks

Comment: I appreciate your help, I think I achieved what I wanted :) you can see here I added some info to the db https://mongoplayground.net/p/eE5ftviVN-F, it's not that important but if there is a way to get rid of the `creator-tracks` and `category-tracks` array of IDs from the query result rather than deleting it after the result, I'd be glad to know!

Comment: you can do the 2 last lookup and at results put their names they will be replaced, instead of  creator-tracks-info put creator-tracks, and instead of related-tracks-info put related-tracks, they will be replaced. You could also $unset them, no need to send those data to the client. For example [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X9SGpTysBqn)

Comment: exactly as I expected, you saved me a lot of frustration :) appreciate your time & help!